# Render pixels to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, draw

I need to render dynamically changing pixels to screen using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android.

I have a method that produces width*height array of colors (RGBA, 4*GLubyte). Also there is PutPixel(x, y, color) method that replaces pixel's color in array that has (x, y) coords.

My solution is: each Draw() method call I call BindTexture, glTexImage2D using array as texture source and then render this texture on plane on full viewport.

Is it a right way? Or there is another better solution?

Comment: Looks correct but it might make more sense to use glTexSubImage2D. Using it might actually enable you to hook it directly from PutPixel if this method is not called too many times per frame. If it is called very many times then rather push the full buffer to the texture once per draw frame.

Comment: I agree with @MaticOblak that rendering the texture once and modifing parts might be a better approach in case you don't update everything on the screen.

However, I can't come up with a use case where you have to draw the screen every time from the cpu leaving out the gpu from calculating the image.

Maybe you should explain the usage more in-depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method might yield performance that is good enough for your needs, particularly if your width*height is less than the full screen resolution. It also has the virtue of being very simple.

However, in general you get much better performance if you can reduce the size of transfers between CPU and GPU during gameplay.

Assuming you never need to read the pixel colour back on the CPU and that you typically only render a few pixels per frame, then your best bet might be to use a render-to-texture approach. Essentially you create a renderable texture that is width*height in size, and have your PutPixel function render coloured points into the texture (batching them up to minimize draw calls).

Comment: Thanks, I know about FBOs. But how should I put pixels on texture? Is the way using PutPixel(x, y, color) { //bind VBO for pixel glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1);} is a good way?

Comment: GL_POINTS is probably as good a way as any, but I'd use glDrawArrays instead of glDrawElements (indices for points aren't useful). I'd also batch it up so that you do as few draw calls as possible (ideally only one per frame).

Comment: Unfortunately, PutPixel() is called width*height times (for each pixel). Then Render() is called. Is there any better solution than mine one?

Comment: If you're re-rendering every pixel every frame on the CPU, then perhaps you shouldn't be using OpenGLES at all. There might be a more appropriate class that Android exposes, perhaps rendering directly to a SurfaceView Canvas is possible? I've only really used OpenGLES/Vulkan on Android so I don't think I can help, but I'd start by investigating SurfaceView and Canvas to see if they offer what you need.